# install jee6 doc on netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java-ee-6

netbeans 6.8

ubuntu 9.10

i am able to build the sample applications, but the doc in the code assistant popup is missing (when type Ctrl + Space)

how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each platform (Version of the JDK, etc) in netbeans, you can specify the location of the JavaDocs

- Select the Tools-> Java Platforms menu
- Select the Platform you're interested in
- In the Javadoc tab, add the zip file or folder with the javadoc files.

The files you want should be in `<Netbeans 6.8 install directory>/enterprise6/docs/javaee6-doc-api.zip`.

However, if you install the EJB and EAR plugins in the Netbeans Platform these should be setup automatically so perhaps a fresh install is required. (Note: I just added them to my Netbeans install on Karmic and the docs worked.)

Comment: so where to download the jee.src.jar ?